Nuget push says "Your package was pushed" but it is not
I'm pushing a nuget package to an Jfrog Artifactory nuget repository.
I tried it with many nuget versions.
nuget.exe push .\MyPackage.2021.10.2.202411201.nupkg username:password -Source https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo -timeout 99999 -verbosity detailed

on the build machine the output is :

NuGet Version: 6.2.1.2
Pushing MyPackage.2021.10.2.202411201.nupkg to
'https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo'...
PUT https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo/
OK https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo/ 772ms
Your package was pushed.

it raises no error. but actually there is nothing uploaded.
on my laptop the same command works fine. the output is a little different:

NuGet Version: 6.2.1.2
Pushing MyPackage.2021.10.2.202411201.nupkg to
'https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo'...
PUT https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo/
Created https://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/myrepo/ 91352ms
Your package was pushed.

why it is not working on the build server. any Idea? is there any detail logs?

The log messages PUT and Created are the HTTP status codes that the web server returned to NuGet, and map to status codes 200 and 201. So, this is really an Artifactory question, not NuGet, as these are the responses Artifactory is returning to NuGet.

the no proxy in nuget.config doesn't accept regex.
I don't know how was it working in the past.
anyway I replaced the regular expression with a simple address list
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy.password" value="blabla" />
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://myproxy.mydomain:8080" />
    <add key="http_proxy.user" value="mydomain\myuser" />
    <!--2024/11/26 add key="no_proxy" value="myartifactory\.myorg\.mydomain" /-->
    <add key="no_proxy" value="myartifactory.myorg.mydomain" />
  </config>

